# Fetching the record id based on the xml unique tag field in which record consist of xml data

Tags: soap-api

Using xml file i"m dumping data into sf org and now I need to save the record id of a particular record into mysql based on the xml file tags.

```
  Here the scenario is using a unique tag in xml I must find out the id of related record in which the particular xml data has been dumped into the SObject .The unique tag data(means it consist of id as data) from the xml should be saved into mysql and the related record which was created based on the xml record id should be stored into the mysql.

  The overall functionality should be done through soap api connector using java.

  Please help me to find out the solution for this scenario.

                Thank You.
```